# How to get at test field from TestNG IInvokedMethodListener?

Tags: java, webdriver, integration-testing, screenshot, testng

I'm using TestNG 6.8 + Selenium WebDriver 2.32 to test the GUI of a web app. In cases of failed tests I would like to take a screenshot of application GUI.

What I have:

- I can detect test failure by implementing testng's `IInvokedMethodListener`
- I also know how to use a webdriver to take a screenshot

What I need:

- to get at my WebDriver instance declared in my AbstractGuiTest class to take a screenshot.

Here's a skeleton of my code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
...
@Listeners(GuiTestListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractGuiTest {
    protected WebDriver driver; //Used by all tests
    ...
}
```

And here's my test listener class, that reacts to failed tests:

```
public class GuiTestListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult itr) {
        if (method.isTestMethod() && !itr.isSuccess()) {
            //Take a screenshot here. But how do I get at the intance of WebDriver declared in the AbstractGuiTest?
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest a way how to get at the instance of WebDriver declared in the AbstractGuitTest, so that I can use it to take a screenshot in the GuiTestListener class?

Comment: A possible solution that came to my mind was to create a static WebDriver field in GuiTestListener which I would set from AbstractGuiTest @BeforeClass setup method. But I was wondering if there was any more systemic solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get it from ITestResult:

```
Object x = itr.getInstance();
AbstractGuiTest currentCase = (AbstractGuiTest)x;
WebDriver driver  = currentCase.getDriver();
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you Justin!

Answer (score 1):

Your possible solution captures the idea well - there should be some place where `WebDriver` instance is shared between tests and listener. Two other solutions come to my mind, which were used on the projects I was involved in or I have read on the internet about.

1. Sharing it through the Singleton "holder" class, like in this [blogpost](http://java.dzone.com/articles/taking-screenshot-when-ui). It is about Groovy and Geb, but it gives the idea.
2. Using dependency injection (e.g. [guiceberry](http://code.google.com/p/guiceberry/)) to inject `WebDriver` in all the places where it is needed. There is an example in guiceberry [tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cyism50KXTMXcvYNbqUXi3gaaNKaXDgjXjpx4rPNet8/preview).

Answer (score 1):

I have something simmilar, I need to take screenshots when a test fails with selenium. All my Test Classes extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests implements TestWithSeleniumDriver, they have annotation @Listeners(ScreenshotForFailedTestListener.class)

```
public interface TestWithSeleniumDriver {
    public RemoteWebDriver getDriver();
}

public class ScreenshotForFailedTestListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {


    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        if (method.isTestMethod() && ITestResult.FAILURE == testResult.getStatus()) {
            if (method.getTestResult().getInstance() instanceof TestWithSeleniumDriver) {
                TestWithSeleniumDriver instance = (TestWithSeleniumDriver) method.getTestResult().getInstance();
                RemoteWebDriver driver = instance.getDriver();
                if (driver != null) {
                    TestingUtils.captureScreen(driver, method);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

public class TestingUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TestingUtils.class);



    public static String captureScreen(RemoteWebDriver driver, IInvokedMethod method) {


        String path;
        try {
            Throwable throwable = method.getTestResult().getThrowable();
            String testClass = method.getTestMethod().getRealClass().getName();
            String packageName = method.getTestMethod().getRealClass().getPackage().getName();
            String shortClassName = method.getTestMethod().getRealClass().getSimpleName();
            String testMethod = method.getTestMethod().getMethodName();

            StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = null;
            for (StackTraceElement traceElement : throwable.getStackTrace()) {
                if (traceElement.getClassName().equals(testClass) && traceElement.getMethodName().equals(testMethod)) {
                    stackTraceElement = traceElement;
                    break;
                }
            }
            WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
            File source = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String drvName = "unknown";
            if (driver instanceof FirefoxDriver)
                drvName = "firefox";
            else if (driver instanceof ChromeDriver)
                drvName = "chrome";
            else if (driver instanceof OperaDriver)
                drvName = "opera";
                // else if ( driver instanceof AndroidDriver )
                // drvName = "android";
            else if (driver instanceof RemoteWebDriver)
                if (driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName() != null)
                    drvName = driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName();
            String day = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
            String hour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
            if (stackTraceElement == null) {
                path = ("./target/screenshots/" + drvName + "/" + "failed" + "/" + //
                        day + "/" + //
                        packageName + "/" + shortClassName + "/" + testMethod + "_noLineInfo_" + //
                        driver.getCurrentUrl().replaceAll("https://", "").replaceAll("/", "_") + "_" + //
                        hour + ".png").replaceAll("__", "_");//
            } else {
                path = ("./target/screenshots/" + drvName + "/" + "failed" + "/" + //
                        day + "/" + //
                        packageName + "/" + shortClassName + "/" + testMethod + "_line-" + stackTraceElement.getLineNumber() + "_" + //
                        driver.getCurrentUrl().replaceAll("https://", "").replaceAll("/", "_") + "_" + //
                        hour + ".png").replaceAll("__", "_");//
            }

            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path));
            String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable);
            logger.error("===========================");
            logger.error("screnshot captured to : " + path);
            logger.error("===========================");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            path = "Failed to capture screenshot: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Code must be adapted a little for your needs

Comment: The solution with the interface is very clean and saves me at least some reflection calls. Thanks for the idea.